# How to update empty Node value using Xpath java?

Tags: java, xpath

I am trying to update empty node value using xpath.When Node has some value set,its getting updated .but if node value is empty,its not getting updated.

Below is code snippet:

```
Document document = dBuilder.parse(new File(filename));
        document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        String expression = "/Document/FIToFICstmrCdtTrf/GrpHdr/TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt";
         NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate(expression, document,
                    XPathConstants.NODESET);

nodes.item(0).setNodeValue("ABC");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way:

```
node.appendChild(document.createTextNode("ABC"));
```

It would be more efficient to fetch a node only instead of the nodelist (if this is the only node):

```
Node node = (Node) xPath.evaluate(expression, document, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

You can check the existing value in this ways:
1, if you use your current xpath, you have to check that is there child node or not:

```
node.getFirstChild() != null // in this case, the node.getFirstChild().getNodeValue() gives back the stored text.
```

2, or, you can test it in this way:

```
 String expression = "/Document/FIToFICstmrCdtTrf/GrpHdr/TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt/text()";
 Node node = (Node) xPath.evaluate(expression, document,
            XPathConstants.NODE);
 node != null // in this case, the node.getNodeValue() gives back the stored text.
```